# Не удается импортировать собственный класс из модуля внутри другого модуля

Tags: python, python-import

Имеется проект со следующей структурой:

```
project_dir:
--main.py
--handlers_dir:
----baseHandler.py
----voiceHandler.py
----__init__.py
```

voiceHandler импортируется в main.py

внутри voiceHandler.py импортирую класс из baseHandler.py следующим образом:

```
from baseHandelr import BaseHandler
```

на что при запуске main.py получаю ошибку:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'baseHandler'
```

Если перенести все handler-ы в корень, то все успешно работает. Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чем может быть проблема? Заранее спасибо.

P.S. Использую Linux, virtualenv, python 3.6.3

Comment: код и сообщение об ошибке не соответствуют друг другу (в коде опечатка)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Полное имя класса: `handlers_dir.baseHandler.BaseHandler`:

```
from handlers_dir.baseHandler import BaseHandler
```

Это называется "абсолютный импорт".

Чтобы импортировать по относительному пути, можно использовать точку внутри `voiceHandler` модуля:

```
from .baseHandler import BaseHandler
```

это называется "явный относительный импорт".

Неявные относительные импорты (вариант в вопросе) убраны из Питона 3. Они не должны использоваться и в Питоне 2 (PEP-328: `from __future__ import absolute_import`).

Если нет особых причин, то следует использовать pep-8 соглашения имён. В частности: модули должны иметь имена в нижнем регистре (маленькие буквы), и если это улучшает читаемость, то возможно подчёркиванием `_` разделённые [pep-8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#package-and-module-names).

Comment: Спасибо большое! Помогло.